# How to print a specific variable from a command's output using grep

Tags: grep

test.txt file:

```
Ext Temperatur:  210.0°
Avg.Speed(All):    62.89mm/s
Avg.Speed(Print):  49.99mm/s
Avg.Speed(Travel): 199.84mm/s
Overall Time (w/o Acceleration): 11:00:41 (39640.65sec)
```

How can I grab `39640.65sec` and `39640.65` as outputs using `grep` and print with php code?

I am using this code but it prints e.g.: `11:00:41 (39640.65sec)`

```
<?php
$gcode_new = "grep -Po '(?<=Overall Time \(w/o Acceleration\):   ).*' test.txt";

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('XXX.61.XXX.227');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'PASS')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$target = $ssh->exec($gcode_new);

echo $target ;
?>
```

Comment: You seem to ask a question about each individual number in that particular data. It would be better if you had asked how to get them all, or tried to give an overview of what it is that you're _actually_ trying to do, and what significance the PHP code plays and why we need to see that in each and every question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
grep -Po "[.0-9]*(?=sec\))"
```

Output:

```
39640.65
```

Comment: If we have two outputs which sends with"sec" how can i select particular line. For eg:

`Overall Time (w/o Acceleration):   11:00:41 (39640.65sec)`
`Overall Time (w/ Acceleration):    6:16:31 (22591.3sec)` How to select only `39640.65`

Answer (score 1):

If mutiple lines occur in file :

Use this to get the first occurrence in the file :

```
grep -m1 -Po "[.0-9]*(?=sec\))" testing.txt
```

To get the last occurrence in the file :

```
grep -Po "[.0-9]*(?=sec\))" testing.txt | tail -1
```